# Change unordered list items into spans with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have two unordered lists inside a div with a known class. I need to change the list items in the first list to spans with the class "time". Next I would like to change the second list items to spans with the class "frequency". Finally I would like to remove the `<ul>` tags leaving only the spans behind in the div. Just like:

```
<div id="training-labels">
<ul>
<li>30 mins</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Annually</li>
<li>First 2 weeks</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

to this

```
<span class="time">30 mins</span>
<span class="frequency">Annually</span>
<span class="frequency">First 2 weeks</span>
```

I have managed to change the contents of each list into spans:

```
$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(1) li').wrapInner('<span class="time" />').contents();
$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(2) li').wrapInner('<span class="frequency" />').contents();
```

But have not been successful stripping out the ul and li tags, leaving only the spans behind.

Is this the best approach or is there a better way to achieve this with JQuery?

I have set up a [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t7ex2gj0/)

```js
$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(1) li').wrapInner('<span class="time" />').contents();

$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(2) li').wrapInner('<span class="frequency" />').contents();
```

```css
.time {
  color: green;
}

.frequency {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="training-labels">
  <ul>
    <li>30 mins</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Annually</li>
    <li>First 2 weeks</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a [new version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74488844/295783) without wrapping and nth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can do following:

```js
$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(1) li').wrap('<span class="time"/>').contents().unwrap();

$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(2) li').wrap('<span class="frequency"/>').contents().unwrap();

$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(1) span').unwrap();
$('#training-labels ul:nth-of-type(1) span').unwrap();
```

```css
.time {
  color: green;
}

.frequency {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="training-labels">
  <ul>
    <li>30 mins</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Annually</li>
    <li>First 2 weeks</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JQuery [`wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method:**

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure.

**JQuery [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method:**

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

**Note: Since no class is attached to the parent div (with the id `training-labels`), both the spans are in the same row.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this worked! Although I replaced the last two lines with $('#training-labels ul span').unwrap(); to unwrap all spans at same time.

Answer (score 2):

If we can be sure all ul1 has times and all ul2 has frequencies

```js
const $div = $('#training-labels');
const $uls = $('ul', $div); // save
$div.empty(); // clear
$uls.each(function(i, ul) {
  $("li", ul).each(function(j, li) {
    $(`<span class="${i===0 ? "time" : "frequency" }">${li.textContent}</span><br/>`)
      .appendTo($div)
  });
});
```

```css
.time {
  color: green;
}

.frequency {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="training-labels">
  <ul>
    <li>30 mins</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Annually</li>
    <li>First 2 weeks</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Otherwise

```js
const $div = $('#training-labels')
$('ul:nth-of-type(1) li', $div).wrapInner('<span class="time" />').contents();
$('ul:nth-of-type(2) li', $div).wrapInner('<span class="frequency" />').contents();
$div.html(function() { 
  return $div.find("span")
    .map(function() { return this.outerHTML })
    .get()
    .join("<br/>"); // or space or something else
});
```

```css
.time {
  color: green;
}

.frequency {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="training-labels">
  <ul>
    <li>30 mins</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Annually</li>
    <li>First 2 weeks</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach

```
let $div = $('#training-labels');
let $time = $('ul:nth-of-type(1) li', $div).clone().wrapInner('<span class="time" />').contents();
let $freq = $('ul:nth-of-type(2) li', $div).clone().wrapInner('<span class="frequency" />').contents();
$div.replaceWith($().add($time).add($freq));
```

This is not dissimilar from the `unwrap` solution except that it is not so tightly tied to the tag structure. The `clone` part isn't strictly required but it means that there is actually only one update to the DOM which happens after the entire replacement has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I wanted to take the time to show a non-JavaScript (or jQuery) CSS-only approach that may work for you, depending on the desired end-result:

```css
/* a simple reset to remove default font-sizes, box-sizing, margins and padding: */
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* removing default list-markers from the <li> elements: */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* wrapping the outer <div> elements which wrap your <ul>
   elements in a <main> element in order to style and
   align the content; this is unnecessary for the demo
   functionality: */
main {
  /* taking advantage of grid display to position items on
     the vertical (block) axis: */
  display: grid;
  /* separating tracks with a 'gutter': */
  gap: 1em;
  /* defining the inline-size - the size of the element
     along the inline-axis (horizontal in most latin-
     derived languages, such as French, English...): */
  inline-size: clamp(15rem, 70vw, 1100px);
  /* a 1em margin before the start of the element on its
     block axis (perpendicular to the inline axis,
     vertical in most Latin-derived languages): */
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  /* using margins to centre the element: */
  margin-inline: auto;
}

/* default styles for the .content elements (the class-name
   given to the <div> elements which wrap the <ul> elements:*/
.content {
  border: 2px solid var(--color, currentColor);
  padding: 0.5em;
}

/* styling the <li> elements as inline-block; which allows them
   to flow inline but take a specified size (inline or block),
   and margins: */
#inlineBlock li {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* using flex layout on the <ul> elements, which positions the
   <li> children along the inline-axis (by default) while allowing
   them to be sized according to their content or declaration: */
#flex ul {
  display: flex;
}

/* this was posted purely for the sake of completeness, and I don't
   recommend it since the track sizing looks more tabular than
   is possibly required: */
#grid {
  display: grid;
  /* this defines two columns with each column sized to fit the
     content within: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, fit-content);
}

#grid ul {
  /* we use this to effectively pretend the <ul> elements don't
     exist, to allow the <li> elements to be placed into the
     grid rather than the <ul> elements: */
  display: contents;
}

/* because each row/column track of a grid has an equal number of
   divisions/"cells", and because we're pretending (display: contents)
   that the <ul> elements don't exist, this is to ensure that
   the <li> contents of the second <ul> don't fill the first row track;
   this can be adjusted if you'd prefer that to happen, but I didn't
   expect that it's required: */
#grid li:only-child {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

/* going back to the land before time, we use a simple floats to
   allow the <li> elements to run inline: */
#float li {
  float: left;
}

/* to ensure the first <li> always starts on a new line: */
#float li:first-child {
  clear: left;
}

/* selecting all <li> elements that are not the :first-child,
   contained within a <div> that does not have an id of "grid": */
.content:is(:not(#grid)) li:not(:first-child)::before {
  /* placing a comma before those elelements: */
  content: ", ";
}

/* selecting the :last-child <li> descendant of .content elements
   (which do not have the id of "grid"), and styling their ::after
   pseudo-element: */
.content:is(:not(#grid)) li:last-child::after {
  /* adding a full-stop/period: */
  content: '.';
}

/* styling the ::after pseudo-element of an <li> which is the :only-child
   of its parent, and within a .content element without the id of "grid": */
.content:is(:not(#grid)) li:only-child::after {
  /* adding a colon after the text of the element: */
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="inlineBlock" class="content" style="--color: hsl(120deg 80% 70% / 1)">
    <ul>
      <li>30 mins</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Annually</li>
      <li>First 2 weeks</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="flex" class="content" style="--color: hsl(160deg 80% 70% / 1)">
    <ul>
      <li>30 mins</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Annually</li>
      <li>First 2 weeks</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="grid" class="content" style="--color: hsl(200deg 80% 70% / 1)">
    <ul>
      <li>30 mins</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Annually</li>
      <li>First 2 weeks</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="float" class="content" style="--color: hsl(240deg 80% 70% / 1)">
    <ul>
      <li>30 mins</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Annually</li>
      <li>First 2 weeks</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pva10cnw/).

References:

CSS:

- [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).
- [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).
- [`block-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/block-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).
- [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
- [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/is).
- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).
- [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where).